# Pyephem: how to calculate time of entering into next constellation

Tags: python, pyephem

Pyephem docs have example how to calculate constellation in which planet is in  certain time.

```
>>> m = ephem.Moon('1980/6/1')
>>> print(ephem.constellation(m))
('Sgr', 'Sagittarius')
```

But how to calculate time when the planet will change constellation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because planets can change direction and speed across the sky, there is no way to predict ahead of time exactly when a planet will cross the boundary to another constellation. The simplest approach would be to step forward in time by one day (or more? or less?) until the output of `constellation()` changes for the planet, and then back up and determine at exactly what time of day the transition occurred.