# Pyephem: time of a planet will be closest to the horizon

Tags: python, pyephem

- Is it possible to calculate time of a planet will be closest to the horizon, when pyephem throws `AlwaysUpError` and `NeverUpError`?

Comment: As with [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27419558/3001761), you could iterate through dates/times to find the minima.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't that be the, for lack of a better term, anti-transit?  It seems to me that if it's cicumpolar, what you're looking for would be roughly 12 hours before/after transit.